# blender finger mesh doesnt follow bone

Tags: mesh, bones, bezier-curves

I'm having this problem this is my first time rigging a bone into a mesh. My problem would be that the "left mid finger" whenever I rotate the bone the mesh doesn't quite follow. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Here is the link for my thesis character.
http://sta.sh/01wwlon92de8

Comment: Mid1.L bone has an influence that goes too far. And this part of the model is also influenced by the right part (Mid1.R)

Comment: A way to see that is to see your mesh in edit mode. Then select a vertex and in the panel to the right (the one obtained with N), you have the list of the groups in which this vertex is involved

Comment: Sir/Ma'am I really don't know that, Is that the vertex group problem? or the weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify this kind of problems.

Enter edit mode for the mesh, select one of the vertices and look at the panel on the right: you will see the bones influences.

Here, we see that one of the right finger bones influences the left part:

[image]

A second problem, is the influence of the mid1.L bone which goes to far along the finger:

[image]

As indicated by @Tak, you can reparent all... but this is not always wanted, so these few explanations may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the upper bone of that finger weighting is wrong. To solve this, select your mesh then then shift+select your armature and choose parent with automatic weighting and the problem will be fixed as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir that solved my problem. I really do appreciate the fast reply sir. Thank you