# How can i fix this ugly deformation

Tags: mesh, armature

I have worked on this charactor for a game im making in BGE. But the deformation on the arms mouth and eyebrows are UGLY. It pretty much is all like this example [image] The way i need it to work is so that the arm bones control the arm part with automatic weighting only the eyebrows control the eyebrows only with automatic weighting and the mouth bones control the mouth part only with automatic weighting. How can i do that?

Oh and did i mention this thing uses automatic weighting for its deformation?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. The body is weighted with the arm bone. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74582/blender-finger-mesh-doesnt-follow-bone/74585#74585 for more information

Comment: That was about a finger bone and one of the answers was put automatic weighting on and thats what this character is on.

Comment: Yes... but you may not use automatic weighting here for arms and legs, at least... the main point in the question I indicated is to identify why there is a problem: the body is weighted to the arms. So remove the arm weights from the body. TLDR: ok for auto weighting, but after that remove the unwanted weights

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the Bone.012 has weighting in the body as shown below:

[image]

Automatic weighting helps you assign weights but sometimes manual weight adjusments is needed especially when in this case Bone.012 is kind of the closest bone to this area.

To fix this select your armature switch to pose mode then select your mesh and switch to weight painting mode. Then select Bone.012 and set Weight to 0.0 as shown below and paint the areas of the body to remove the weighting from it.

[image]

Keep painting with 0 weights until no vertices are assigned to this bone as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]