# Which bone influence should I modify to make the shirt sleeve bigger than the forearm

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, rigify

I'm trying to increase the size of the shirt sleeve because the forearm is bigger than it and it's not natural. Look at this example,looks like there is a bone on the forearm that has too little influence on the sleeve,but I don't know what's this. I'm using the standard rigify armature...can someone give me a suggestion ? thanks.

[image: wrong influence between bones image]

Comment: Hard to say, just with an image. If the mesh does not follow the bone, that's probably because another bone as some influence on it. Some indication to find it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74582/blender-finger-mesh-doesnt-follow-bone/74585#74585

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: https://uploadfiles.io/67f47

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T51073